# How to set the Biztalk Flat File Disassembler to handle the below flat file?

Tags: biztalk

1000a1999
@ AAAA0008      DD    384771  WWWW HHHH TOWER
7000a7999
@ BBBB07        EE    384876  SSS HHH VVVV 'A'
10000a13000
@ CCCC0011      FF    381845  TTTTTTTTTT BBBBBB HK LTD
! DDDD0011      FF    481845  TTTTTTTTTT BBBBBB HK LTD

Those lines like 1000a1999 are headers and those lines started with @ or ! are records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the flat file schema wizard to generate your schema.  In that wizard, you'll have to specify the TAG Identifiers for every type of record.

- 1000a1999 should tag identifier for your Header records (depends on how many of those choices you have)
- Then specify repeating record for the records that start with @ or ! (again, specify the right Tag identifier here to be @ or !).  (you can mark the other records as ignore in the schema wizard, so you don't have to specify their structure multiple times)

After that, the generated schema will require some tweaking, I believe.  You may have to group some records into a Choice with multiple occurances, etc.

Not a trivial schema at first sight, but should be possible to parse it.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks. Finally can parse the flat file using the suggested xsd in visual studio. However, After deploying the dll to Biztalk server, the validation is still failed. Dont know why the visual studio validation is not aligned with Biztalk server validation.

Comment: you might need to tweak things (for example: use parser optimization and set it to complex).  it would also help if you would post the error you get

Answer (score 0):

After doing the Flat File Schema Wizard Walkthrough, use that to develop this schema.  We can help with any issues after that.